# How to save results in txt file but not the same like print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi with this code I get numbers.

```
n = 1000

while n > 500:
    print(n, end=', ')
    n -= 50
    print(n)
    n -= 100
```

I get this result

```
1000, 950
850, 800
700, 650
550, 500
```

How I can save this in txt but this way? First number to be second and second to be first.

```
950, 1000
800, 850
650, 700
500, 550
```

I tried this but not work

```
f = open("test.txt", 'w')
print(n, end=', ', file=f)
print(n, file=f)
f.close()
```

And tried this

```
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
   print('Filename:', filename, file=f)
```

Can someone to help me?

Comment: format the text first the way you want it before trying to save it.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: Little inconsistency: your code shows `n=10000` while your output starts at `1000`.

Comment: Have you done any research, read the documentation? There are already mountains of resources on the subject.

Comment: Yes I am. But nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways this can be done, but the way I would go is to calculate the two numbers and format the string you want to write to file first. Something like this:

```
f = open("test.txt", 'w')
n = 1000
while n > 500:
    second = n    # second number to print
    first = n - 50   # first number to print
    f.write('%d,%d\n' % (first, second))   # print to file
    n -= 150          # decrement for the total of 150 per round
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but I need another results. With yours code I get this

Comment: Check it again: I just fixed some logic

Comment: 9950,9900
    9800,9750
    9650,9600
    9500,9450
9350,9300
9200,9150
    9050,9000
    8900,8850
    8750,8700
    8600,8550
    8450,8400
    8300,8250
    8150,8100
    8000,7950
    7850,7800
    7700,7650
    7550,7500
    7400,7350
    7250,7200

Comment: You also have `n=10000` instead of `n=1000` in your posted code: I fixed this. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty ugly example but might be easier to understand this way.

```py
n = 10000

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  while n > 500:
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(n)
    n -= 50
    tmp.append(n)
    n -= 100
    print(tmp[1], tmp[0])
    f.write(f"{tmp[1]}, {tmp[0]}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search give a nice source from w3 schools. 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

To summarize:

You need to replace the

```
print(n, end=', ', file=f)
```

with

```
f.write("Add your info here")
```

Doing this with the `with` thing:

```
with open("your_file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("The stuff you want in the file here")
```

You can also read from a file with the appropriately named `read()` command

```
f = open("your_file.txt", "r")
f.read()
```

Comment: In python, the `print()` function can be used to write to file by using the `file` argument, as long as the object written is not binary. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)